# Compile changes only after editing another class

Tags: c++, sfml

so i have this weird problem -
im using sfml with c++ and i want to edit a game-screen ( i created a screen class to be derived by different levels and screens of the game ) but the weird thing is that when i change things in the class ( for example if im trying to change the pixel movement rate of a sprite ) and than i compile and run the program i see absolutly no changes, but if i change another class afterwards ( does not matters which class, any class at all would work ) than ill see the changes in the game-screen that i created...
i really dont know whats the problem here so im asking for your help

by the way if its matters there's the class ( no header, only .cpp )

```
#include "Screen.hpp"
#include "Sprite.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;

class GameScreen : public rce::Screen
{
private:
    rce::Sprite s;

public:
    GameScreen() : Screen()
    {
    }

    void Load()
    {
        s.SetImage("circle.png");
    }

    void Unload()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        s.SetX(s.GetX()+1);
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        s.Draw();
    }
};
```

Comment: This may be silly, but are you sure the program gets fully compiled? For example if you are writing your own Makefiles, are you sure you have made the dependencies right?

Comment: i am using visual c++ express 2010... i believe the program gets fully compiled, although i feared that it might be the problem. not sure about it though :O

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem them, but either way, try changing your class and do a full rebuild, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: tried that already actualy... didnt do anything :(

Comment: Try rebuilding all, and also, make sure that all `.lib` files are erased in every folder in your "Additional Library Directories" list (unless they are external libraries).  Then go to the folder where the `.exe` was built (check the file creation time) and then running that `.exe` file directly.

Comment: didnt work either... i have no idea what could be the problem here.. im so confused @_@

Comment: Are you sure the source is saved before compiling ? You can manually delete *.obj files in your project directory, thus forcing a recompilation. Or you can Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: did both of these already and nothing helped... i think its a bug

Answer (score 1):

If you working multiple file with C/C++, Compilers of C/C++ compile each *.c or *cpp file and make it *.o, or *obj file in some of compilers.gcc used *.o . Then linker links them together. When you recompile an special file, you should compile its dependencies.